# Asp.Net Razor com Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, rest, asp.net-web-api

tenho uma duvida e já pesquisei em diversos sites mas não obtive a resposta. Desenvolvo sistemas em **.Net com C# no padrão MVC** e utilizo a apresentação na tela na forma tradicional View com Razor.

Acontece que tenho percebido que vários sistemas web disponibilizados ultimamente tem apresentado cada vez mais uma experiencia ao usuário igual a uma aplicação Desktop, ou seja, com quase nada de Reloads por requisição e uma maior interatividade com os eventos dos campos.

Muitos destes sistemas utilizam **Knockout, Vue, Aurelia e principalmente AngularX** em suas Views, ou melhor, utilizam somente o MC e o V fica por conta de outra tecnologia.

Agora vem a minha questão, como não domino nenhuma destas tecnologias (ainda), com a experiencia de vocês, qual seria a melhor forma para trabalhar com as Views de tal forma que eu conseguisse criar as sistemas com uma experiencia ao usuário mais próxima das fornecidas pelas tecnologias citadas anteriormente mantendo omeu padrão de desenvolvimento MVC com Razor? Pelo poder que as Views geradas com Razor oferece, muito ***provavelmente*** eu não devo estar utilizando algum recurso que esta ferramenta possa disponibilizar?! - Pelo que pude observar uma das coisas que ***"devo"*** 
trabalhar para chegar no resultado esperado é trabalhar com Json (até ai tudo bem) como se a minha aplicação fosse uma Web API - estou certo?

Espero ter sido claro na apresentação da minha duvida.

Desde já agradeço pela força!

Comment: Se o que você quer é só que partes do seu sistema seja assíncronos, você pode pesquisar por partial view, ajax forms ou a sugestão do Cigano mesmo...

Comment: Aline, obrigado pelas dicas. Quando você diz ajax forms é o mesmo que Ajax.BeginFor() ? se sim , vc acredita que este pode resolver em grande partes os meus questionamentos?

Comment: Se forem só partes do sistema que tu quer enviar dados ou manipular se forma assíncrona, vai funcionar sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pelo que pude observar uma das coisas que "devo" trabalhar para chegar no resultado esperado é trabalhar com Json (até ai tudo bem) como se a minha aplicação fosse uma Web API - estou certo?

Melhor ainda: trabalhar com a Web API propriamente dita. A Web API surgiu exatamente na sua constatação: como fazer o sistema MVC trabalhar sem depender da camada de apresentação?

> qual seria a melhor forma para trabalhar com as Views de tal forma que eu conseguisse criar as sistemas com uma experiencia ao usuário mais próxima das fornecidas pelas tecnologias citadas anteriormente mantendo omeu padrão de desenvolvimento MVC com Razor?

Primeiro, desenvolvendo os métodos que respondam à nova camada de apresentação dentro do próprio sistema MVC. Depois, migrando essa estrutura para um sistema puramente em Web API. [Eu tenho um curso que explica como fazer isso](http://www.codingcraft.com.br/2016/08/10/coding-craft-asp-net-mvc-e-asp-net-web-api-modulo-1-turma-de-10-de-setembro-de-2016/), se estiver interessado (a ementa é a mesma).

Ou seja, dado um método que normalmente devolve uma *View*:

```
public ActionResult DevolveView()
{
    ...
    return View(objetos);
}
```

Você faz uma cópia deste método de forma a devolver um JSON estruturado:

```
public JsonResult DevolveView()
{
    ...
    return Json(objetos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

E depois cria um *Controller* em separado para estes novos métodos usando JSON:

```
public MeuControllerApi : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult DevolveView()
    {
        ...
        return Ok(objetos);
    }
}
```

Isso é apenas uma sugestão. O ideal é fazer um tutorial mais denso para compreender como essa migração funciona.

Comment: Cigano, agradeço pelas respostas dos meus questionamentos. Com relação aos seus exemplos ficou muito claro como devo servir a view, o meu problema é exatamente em como apresentar uma View utilizando Razor e obtendo o retorno em Json? Sei que JQuery é capaz de me ajudar, mas até onde pude entender o retorno "data" não preenche diretamente os inputs da View. Falo muito em View com Razor , pois atualmente é o que mais conheço dentro do cenário .Net MVC. Com relação ao seu curso, o mesmo é apresentado em video ou somente em livro? Acho que uso pouco do poder do Razor e o seu livro pode me ajudar!

Comment: Sobre sua primeira pergunta, você precisa usar um *framework* mais robusto que o jQuery para conseguir. Minhas sugestões são Aurelia, React e Angular 2, nesta ordem.

Comment: Sobre meu curso, as aulas são feitas por *hangouts* e gravadas em vídeo por mim. O aluno fica com uma cópia para assistir quando quiser. Há o livro que serve como material de apoio ao conteúdo apresentado em *hangout*. O curso ajuda sim bastante no uso do Razor.

Comment: Olá Cigano, pelo visto para conseguir oque desejo não tem outra saída a não ser partir para um Framework MVVM, mas estes frameworks não faz com que eu deixe de utilizar uma view com Razor? Outra coisa, considerando a ordem apresentada na sua ultima resposta, devo iniciar com o Aurélia? mais uma vez muito obrigado pela força!!!

Comment: Cigano, com relação ao seu curso, consigo todas as informações no link http://www.codingcraft.com.br - Preço, prazo de pagamento entre outros?

Comment: "Olá Cigano, pelo visto para conseguir oque desejo não tem outra saída a não ser partir para um Framework MVVM, mas estes frameworks não faz com que eu deixe de utilizar uma view com Razor?", exatamente. Você passa a não ter geração de HTML pelo servidor. Tudo o que o servidor gera é JSON e o JavaScript do browser interpreta esse JSON para gerar um resultado dinâmico em tela.

Comment: "Outra coisa, considerando a ordem apresentada na sua ultima resposta, devo iniciar com o Aurélia?" Sim.

Comment: Sobre o curso, vamos continuar o contato por e-mail, Facebook ou Twitter. Veja meu perfil com todas as possibilidades de contato que tenho. De qualquer forma, sim, o preço e o prazo de pagamento são os mesmos do link.